# How to change subcategory order in Joomla

Tags: joomla3.3

I have a category blog page which lists subcategories.  These categories seem to be ordered by ID despite having changed the category order option to "category manager order".  I also tried editing the sql itself but 'order' is not a column on categories like it is for articles so no luck there.

How can I order my subcategories in the backend and have them come out in the same order on the site?

Joomla 3.3

Comment: Please tag your joomla version.

Answer (score 0):

I added order integers to the "note" field for each category and ordered my sql by the note value.

I suspect there is still a more Joomla-y way to do this though.